# Interpretation of Classifier Result in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I am running classification algorithm in Weka. But I am unsure about some of results that Weka generate for reporting purposes.

In classification problem (either Yes=have disease or No = do not have disease), Weka produce result for each classifier. But also provide weighted result at bottom for both classifier.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtWC0.png)

My question is, from reporting prospective what score should I be reporting on? (Basically I want to compare my results with other people results)

As per weka result (attached) for F-Measure; will it be 91 percent or 89 percent? Same applies for all other measurements (recall and precision).

Also, I want to know in research papers what score is reported for any given classifier? Weighted or for classifier that we are trying to predict, for example in my case, only report on result for'Yes' score?

Many thanks,

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Include your data as text: not a link, not a screen shot, but text within the posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case defines what you report.  In general, research papers report the entire confusion matrix and statistics tables.  This allows readers to extract the data needed for the way *they* will use the research.

If a patient receives a "disease-free" result from this classifier, there's chance of about 18% that the person actually *does* have the disease.  Is this acceptable?  That's not a question SO (Stack Overflow) can answer: that's the use case.

If you insist on describing the test with a single, scalar statistic, you need to clarify the use case, and report that single metric accurately.  In general, the summary f-measure (weighted) is what you report.